# How to include heavy model training in a FastAPI endpoint?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, fastapi

There are many resources online describing usage of fastapi for prediction using a pre-trained model that is static. **What if we would like to have an endpoint to initiate retraining of new data?** It seems that fastapi's BackgroundTasks is not suitable for a training of several minutes that would take up a lot of CPU.

I am wondering how the following skeleton code could roughly be extended, assuming the underling model is a deep learning model (so quite long training).

```py
import numpy as np
import pickle
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import os

app = FastAPI(title="dummy app")

# represents a particular datapoint

class Datapoint(BaseModel):
    feature1: float
    feature2: float
    feature3: float

    
@app.on_event("startup")
def load_model():
    # load model from pickle file
    #print(os.getcwd())
    #print(os.listdir())
    with open("../app/model.pkl", "rb") as file:
        global model
        model = pickle.load(file)
        

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
        

@app.post("/predict")
def predict(data: Datapoint):
    data_point = np.array(
        [
            [
                data.feature1,
                data.feature2,
                data.feature3,
            ]
        ]
    )

    pred = model.predict(data_point).tolist()
    pred = pred[0]
    print(pred)
    return {"Prediction": pred}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You better use a dedicated machine to do asynchronous background jobs. Otherwise you risk stopping the API for new requests. Take a look at [Celery](https://pypi.org/project/celery/) for background jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @lepsch , I found that interesting article also thanks to your guide towards celery: https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-ml-models-in-production-with-fastapi-and-celery-7063e539a5db